# Spring Boot GraphQL: Any class to extends/implements which executes before sending GraphQL response to client similar to ContainerResponseFilter REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, graphql-java

In REST API, we can create our custom Filter class by implementing `ContainerResponseFilter`
interface and override its

> public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext, final ContainerResponseContext responseContext))

method. This `filter()` executes on every request before sending response to client.

Similar to this, do we have any way in GraphQL with Spring Boot to create our class and executes before sending response to client?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You don't mention what you're using right now to handle the communication with the client, either in the question or the tags. Do you have a custom controller, do you  use Spring GraphQL, or any of the other various starters for GraohQL. Also, why not handle filtering at the field level? Top level filter sounds like a very blunt approach with ad-hoc querying that GraphQL enables.

Comment: @kaqqao I have updated my question for better understanding, hope this time it is clear now.